# Changes to script.js doesn't happen on my live website on Hostinger

Tags: javascript, reveal.js, scrollreveal.js

I've built my locally on Visual Code studio, there was a scroll Reveal effect (left & right reveal) that I wanted to remove by just removing the last two lines code from script.js:

```
/*==================== scroll reveal ====================*/
ScrollReveal({
    // reset: true,
    distance: '120px',
    duration: 1600,
    delay: 150
});

ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content, .main-text, .heading', { origin: 'top' });
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-img, .services-container, .portfolio-box, .contact form', { origin: 'bottom' });
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content h1, .about-img', { origin: 'left' });
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content p, .about-content', { origin: 'right' });
```

To be like this:

```
/*==================== scroll reveal ====================*/
ScrollReveal({
    // reset: true,
    distance: '120px',
    duration: 1600,
    delay: 150
});

ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content, .main-text, .heading', { origin: 'top' });
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-img, .services-container, .portfolio-box, .contact form', { origin: 'bottom' });
```

And it worked perfectly on my desktop when tested locally.

But the issue is that when I upload the files to Hostinger and test my website live, I see that the left and right scroll reveal effect still exist even though I removed those two lines.

[My website](http://salaheddinesouiss.com)

I tried so many troubelshoots but I can't figure it out myself! I'm pretty new to coding.

Help please!

Comment: Those lines are indeed removed on your website. Did you clear your cache?

Comment: @DallogFheir I tested it now from a new device it looks good! I don't know why on my laptop it doesn't load correctly on my browser even though I cleared all of my browser data, cash, and cookies. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use incognito mode in your browser to avoid the caching problem or use a different browser for testing (which is recommended anyways)